# String cast to decimal in Where, C# FbConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

There is a condition on column written in text:

```
SomeDecimalColumn = 1234567890 <use your favorite decimal here>
```

and I need to have a query to a Firebird database to include this condition.
Naturally I tried:

```
//query is a QueryObject of firebird database connection (FbConnection).
// SELECT "A"."SomeDecimalColumn" as C1 
// FROM "MYTABLE" AS "A"
// # SomeDecimalColumn has type DECIMAL(18,0)
var predicate = "SomeDecimalColumn = 1234567890"
query = query.Where(predicate);
//query:
// SELECT "A"."SomeDecimalColumn" as C1 
// FROM "MYTABLE" AS "A" 
// WHERE CAST(1234567890 AS DECIMAL(9,0)) = "A"."SomeDecimalColumn"
```

It bugs me that it casts string to `DECIMAL(9,0)` by default. Is there a way to force casting in where to a certain precision, i.e. force `DECIMAL(18,0)`?

I can't parse this string to separate ColumnName from Value.
I don't know a priori what kind of predicate I'm going to get.

Comment: Try something like this :             CultureInfo info = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            info.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 5;

            Convert.ToDecimal("123", info);

Comment: @jdweng, does query object reads global culture variable?

Comment: A predicate is a method in this case returns a Boolean.  So any code you place in the predicate (including) my code is valid.  My code reads the culture.

Comment: @jdweng, i'm confused and don't get your message well. Could you elaborate further? My problem is with where clause, that determines type of cast on its own.

Comment: Instead of Cast use Convert.ToDecimal("123", info)

Comment: @jdweng, i do not use Cast. I just pass my string expession to where, and it creates a cast clause. To Convert.ToDecimal i have to parse my string expression, and there can be any kind of logical expression written in string.

Comment: The use the code that is commented out.

Comment: I'd suggest also asking this question on the [firebird-net-provider Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider)